# Set location of templates of Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, configuration

When I first get Cordova to create a project typing 
"cordova create appfolder com.whatever.appid AppName"
it downloads the iconset for all platforms and template for www folder into .cordova\lib\www\cordova[VERSION]\

Then I add platform:
"cordova platform add android" which causes cordova to download the template for android application project folder into .cordova\lib\android\cordova[VERSION].

Is there a way to configure the location for these folders?

Currently I am on Cordova Version 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I have found the solution.

If you create the cordova project specifying location of www template like this:

```
cordova create appfolder com.whatever.appid AppName --copy-from="source\path\of\www"
```

a config.json is created in appfolder.cordova. You can add an entry to this config.json like this:

```
"android": {
  "uri": "path\to\android\template",
  "version": "dev",
  "id": "cordova-android-dev"
},
"ios": {
  "uri": "path\to\ios\template",
  "version": "dev",
  "id": "cordova-ios-dev"
}
```

Then you can run cordova platforms add android which will use the location of templates as specified in this json.

I found this in a mailing archive: https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@cordova.apache.org/msg13005.html